# Type or namespace name 'OfficeOpenXml' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, teamcity, epplus

I just added the EPPlus and EPPlus.Extensions NuGet packages to my solution to handle upload of Excel docs.  Everything is working fine locally, but when I build with Team City, I get the "'OfficeOpenXml' could not be found" error.

I added a NuGet Installer step as the first Build Step as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530953/the-type-or-namespace-name-officeopenxml-could-not-be-found-error).  (So this is the first NuGet package in this solution.)  I selected my main solution file as the Solution parameter.  EPPlus is installed on a project inside that.  However, the error persists.

I'm still on VS 2010 (will be up grading in the next week or so) and the .NET 4.0 Framework.

In Team City, the NuGet Packages tab does list EPPlus (4.0.5) and EPPlus.Extensions (1.0.0.0).

I can find the DLL's in my solution and add them to GIT, and this does work, but I don't believe this is the correct solution.

**Build Log**

```
[13:57:04]Updating sources: server side checkout (1s)
[13:57:04][Updating sources] Using vcs information from agent file: c1ee5fcf55d7468f.xml
[13:57:04][Updating sources] Building incremental patch for VCS root: MSHSAA BitBucketStaging; checkout rules: =>; revision: d925721c189f9eebd5c2b6ab6f1a66f3ea9d99a5 --> b114606aa4d6ddb9b47b46a1b5c998b64081ca10
[13:57:06][Updating sources] Repository sources transferred: 29.88 KB total
[13:57:06][Updating sources] Updating C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f
[13:57:06]Step 1/2: NuGet Installer (NuGet Installer) (1s)
[13:57:06][Step 1/2] scan: Searching for nuget.config files
[13:57:06][scan] Found packages folder: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\packages
[13:57:06][scan] Found list of packages.config files: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\packages\repositories.config
[13:57:06][scan] Scanning projects in solution file: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\MSHSAA.sln
[13:57:06][scan] Found project C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\Web
[13:57:06][scan] Found project C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\DataAccess.Linq\DataAccess.Linq.csproj
[13:57:06][scan] Found project C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\UI\UI.csproj
[13:57:06][scan] Found project C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\Web_deploy\Web_deploy.wdproj
[13:57:06][scan] Found project C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\Controls\Controls.csproj
[13:57:06][scan] Found project C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\Utility\Utility.csproj
[13:57:06][scan] Found project C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\MSHSAA_Mobile\MSHSAA_Mobile.csproj
[13:57:06][Step 1/2] restore: Restoring NuGet packages for MSHSAA.sln
[13:57:06][restore] NuGet command: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\tools\NuGet.CommandLine.DEFAULT\tools\NuGet.exe restore C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\MSHSAA.sln
[13:57:06][restore] Starting: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script9137858174769788034.cmd
[13:57:06][restore] in directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f
[13:57:07][restore] MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '12.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin'.
[13:57:07][restore] All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
[13:57:07][restore] Process exited with code 0

[13:57:07]Step 2/2: Staging (Visual Studio (sln)) (24s)
[13:57:07][Step 2/2] Starting: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.MsBuildBootstrap.exe /workdir:C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f /msbuildPath:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
[13:57:07][Step 2/2] in directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f
[13:57:09][Step 2/2] MSHSAA.sln.teamcity: Build target: TeamCity_Generated_Build (22s)
[13:57:09][MSHSAA.sln.teamcity] TeamCity_Generated_Build (22s)
[13:57:09][TeamCity_Generated_Build] MSBuild (22s)
[13:57:09][MSBuild] MSHSAA.sln: Build target: Rebuild (21s)
[13:57:09][MSHSAA.sln] ValidateSolutionConfiguration
[13:57:09][MSHSAA.sln] Rebuild (21s)
[13:57:09][Rebuild] MSBuild (21s)
[13:57:09][MSBuild] Web.metaproj: Build target: Rebuild (9s)
[13:57:19][MSBuild] Web_deploy\Web_deploy.wdproj.metaproj: Build target: Rebuild (12s)
[13:57:19][Web_deploy\Web_deploy.wdproj.metaproj] Rebuild (12s)
[13:57:19][Rebuild] MSBuild (12s)
[13:57:19][MSBuild] Web_deploy\Web_deploy.wdproj: Build target: Rebuild (12s)
[13:57:19][Web_deploy\Web_deploy.wdproj] CleanWDP
[13:57:19][Web_deploy\Web_deploy.wdproj] ResolveProjectReferences
[13:57:19][Web_deploy\Web_deploy.wdproj] AfterResolveReferences
[13:57:19][Web_deploy\Web_deploy.wdproj] BeforeBuild
[13:57:19][Web_deploy\Web_deploy.wdproj] AspNetCompiler (12s)
[13:57:19][AspNetCompiler] AspNetCompiler (12s)
[13:57:19][AspNetCompiler] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /Web -p C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\Web -u -f -c obj\Staging\TempBuildDir 
[13:57:29][AspNetCompiler] c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\Web\Modules\ClassNavigation.ascx.cs(15, 0): warning CS0109: The member 'Modules_ClassNavigation.ActivityLevelGenderID' does not hide an inherited member. The new keyword is not required.
[13:57:29][AspNetCompiler] c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\Web\Modules\ClassNavigation.ascx.cs(26, 0): warning CS0109: The member 'Modules_ClassNavigation.ActivityLevelGender' does not hide an inherited member. The new keyword is not required.
[13:57:29][AspNetCompiler] c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\Web\Modules\ClassNavigation.ascx.cs(36, 0): warning CS0109: The member 'Modules_ClassNavigation.CurrentSchoolYear' does not hide an inherited member. The new keyword is not required.
[13:57:29][AspNetCompiler] c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\Web\Modules\ClassNavigation.ascx.cs(48, 0): warning CS0109: The member 'Modules_ClassNavigation.CurrentClassNumber' does not hide an inherited member. The new keyword is not required.
[13:57:29][AspNetCompiler] c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\Web\Modules\ClassNavigation.ascx.cs(60, 0): warning CS0109: The member 'Modules_ClassNavigation.CurrentDistrictNumber' does not hide an inherited member. The new keyword is not required.
[13:57:29][AspNetCompiler] c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\Web\Modules\ClassNavigation.ascx.cs(581, 0): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected
[13:57:30][AspNetCompiler] c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\Web\Modules\CompetitionEdit.ascx.cs(91, 0): warning CS0472: The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'
[13:57:30][AspNetCompiler] c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\Web\Modules\CompetitionEdit.ascx.cs(110, 0): warning CS0472: The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'bool' is never equal to 'null' of type 'bool?'
[13:57:31][AspNetCompiler] c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c1ee5fcf55d7468f\Web\Accounting\ExternalInvoices.aspx.cs(17, 0): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OfficeOpenXml' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
[13:57:31][Step 2/2] Process exited with code 1
[13:57:31][Step 2/2] MSBuild output
[13:57:31][Step 2/2] Step Staging (Visual Studio (sln)) failed
[13:57:31]Publishing artifacts
[13:57:31]Publishing internal artifacts
[13:57:31]Build finished
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the packages.config file is checked into source control? Can you provide the build log for the NuGet installer step?

Comment: @EvolveSoftwareLtd Yes, packages.config is checked in.  Build Log added.

Comment: I don't see the build log for step 1 (which I assume is the nuget install)

Comment: @EvolveSoftwareLtd Here you go.

Comment: You look to be currently using restore and it's saying all packages are already installed and there's no reference to a package.confg file. Can you try using the following settings. 1 Restore Mode = Install, 2 Disable looking up packages from local machine cache. This forces a fresh install of the packages using the config files that are found for each project in the solution - And see what happens

Comment: @EvolveSoftwareLtd hmmm... just opened the Packages older, and Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.5 is checked in along with other things, but EPPlus is not.  This is on the main solution folder/packages where the repositories.xml file also resides.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116131/discussion-between-evolve-software-ltd-and-john-pasquet).